# Embed AngularJS App in CRM 2011

Tags: angularjs, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to embedd a single page angularJS app in to CRM 2011 (making use of routing and the ng-view directive). I have loaded all the appropriate files in to my solutions Web Resources and have modified the SiteMap to display a navigation link to the 'index.html' of the app. Everything is working as expected at this point.

What is not working however, is trying to start the angularjs app on a different 'page' e.g. index.html/#/anotherpage

I am unable to append the '/#/anotherpage' to the url in the sitemap editor as it complains that it is not a valid resource. Is there a way to do this or do I need to break all my sub pages in to separate pages in order to display them as individual navigation links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a 'clean' solution to this. Instead, I created a web resource that just redirected immediately to the appropriate url